# Is there a proper way to use Python code from PHP?

Tags: php, python

There is some functionality written in python which I need to use in PHP. I need to pass parameters to python function and pass result(at least simple types: integer, float, tuple, etc.) back into php?. Can it be done?

Comment: python & PHP are 2 different programming languages. You want a converter?

Comment: Would you accept `yes` as an answer? :) Seriously though, some more context and background would be useful

Comment: Actually, you can use the shell to execute other programs easily. The same way you would fire a shell script in PHP, you can call a Python program and get the return output value as long as it prints directly to stdout or you pass a special file stream handle. The question is, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **XML-RPC** (remote procedure calling). It's dead-simple to setup a Python-Server for this, and in PHP, go with http://php.net/manual/de/ref.xmlrpc.php .

E.g., as example (taken from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html))

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler

# Restrict to a particular path.
class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

# Create server
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000),
                            requestHandler=RequestHandler)
server.register_introspection_functions()

# Register pow() function; this will use the value of
# pow.__name__ as the name, which is just 'pow'.
server.register_function(pow)

# Register a function under a different name
def adder_function(x,y):
    return x + y
server.register_function(adder_function, 'add')

# Register an instance; all the methods of the instance are
# published as XML-RPC methods (in this case, just 'div').
class MyFuncs:
    def div(self, x, y):
        return x // y

server.register_instance(MyFuncs())

# Run the server's main loop
server.serve_forever()
```

sets up a fully working XML-RPC-server.

Then every method of `MyFuncs` is available for use from any programming language that supports XML-RPC, including PHP.

Answer (score 3):

you can run any external script from php using [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

or

Create a web service to access. This would be the best method.