# Calling a Python script from MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call python function from MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780/call-python-function-from-matlab)

Is there a way to call functions in a Python script from MATLAB, and if so, how?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  In the general case, I think what you're asking for is impossible, but there might be a workaround depending upon the details.  There's also a fair chance you're suffering from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and asking the wrong question.

Comment: I have a python class containing two functions i need to call those functions in MATLAB.

Comment: For the revised question, [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780/call-python-function-from-matlab) on calling Python functions from MATLAB might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to do something non-trivial. Matlab doesn't have any binding of Python-scripts, and also I don't know of a really good substitute. You can choose between two roads, maybe one can help you a little bit (though both are non-trivial, just as your task):

### Convert to Python

In nowadays, Python is a valid substitute for most use cases of Matlab. There are libraries for munerical calculations, scientific routines, a great plotting library and a fantastic community that will try to help you with all your problems. And, it's free.

If you only have a couple of Matlab scripts running or you just started using Matlab I'd recommend consideringa a change of platform. To convert your existing Matlab-scripts, you could try the [Open Matlab-Python-Converter](http://ompc.juricap.com/).

### Create a webservice using Python and access it from Matlab

The cleanest way to execute Python-Code from Matlab is to setup a webservice with Python and call this webservice from Matlab. This sounds really complicated, but it isn't. For small projects, I'd recommend XML-RPC. You can look at [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352983/is-there-a-proper-way-to-use-python-code-from-php/14353762#14353762) to see an example of a small XML-RPC-server. If your methods exist, it'Ss easy to adapt to your needs, just import these methods and offer them as webservice calls.

On the Matlab side, you must stick to third-party tools for connecting to an XML-RPC server, e.g., [Apache XML-RPC jars](https://wiki.nbic.nl/index.php/Matlab_XMLRPC).

It might become complicated when you want to pass in other variables than primitives, e.g., arrays. I have no experience how well this works.